# How does dot net core process Arg.NotNull and Contract.Requires assets

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, code-contracts

In the [aspnet-api-versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/8afc8f9ae41a1ff2420f2eb407f802c25ef64ecf/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/ApplicationModels/DefaultApiControllerFilter.cs) I have found out a codeblock:

```
DefaultApiControllerFilter( IEnumerable<IApiControllerSpecification> pecifications )
        {
            Arg.NotNull( specifications, nameof( specifications ) );
            this.specifications = specifications.ToArray();
        }
```

The interested block is `Arg.NotNull( value, "text" );` from the `Microsoft` namespace.

And there are several similar asserts in the code. Another example is `Contract.Requires()` from `System.Diagnostics.Contracts`

Tried to search over Microsoft docs about work principles but didn't found info.

So maybe could help to find out how does it work: like  [postsharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) code rewrite, provide runtime conditional check as `Debug.Assert` or maybe simply throws exceptions(but it doesn't mention in docs)?

Answer (score 1):

They are code contracts (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/code-contracts/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fcontracts%2Fuserdoc.pdf)

Unfortunately they didn't really take off and the project was kind of abandoned, which is a shame as they had potential.

Comment: after sources download found out that there are 2 different namespaces - Microsoft and  System.Diagnostics.Contracts - so updated question text

Comment: @DimaS the key word is `abandoned`. Even if you compile the source for .NET Core, there are no tools to validate the contracts

Answer (score 0):

After downloading library sources, compile and get look through compiled code found out that `Microsoft::Arg` is just a [shared code project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows) with a method

```
internal static void NotNull<T>(T value, string name) where T : class 
    {
      if ((object) value == null)    throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
```

and the `Contract.Requires(condition)` is an [Code Contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts) Assert codegenration extension which ...doesn't produce any code becuse of absence of the assert post build event. [The similar sutuation on stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052640/how-does-contract-ensures-work)  .

Comment: And that's become obsolete now that .NET Core 3.0 and C# 8 added nullable references. This snippet isn't an example of code contracts either, it's just a guard clause. Nullable references or Roslyn analyzers are far more powerful than that.