# Why is List<T>.Count a signed int? Can List<T>.Count ever be negative?

Tags: c#, .net, list, comparison-operators, empty-list

```
public class List<T>
{
     public int Count
        {
            get;
        }
}
```

I noticed `Count` is an `int`, will the result be less than 0？

If `Count` could be less than `0`, I have to write that：

```
if(myList.Count < 1)
{
  
}
```

otherwise I can write that:

```
if(myList.Count == 0)
{
  
}
```

Comment: No it can't be less than zero.

Comment: No, count can't be less than zero. This is a common sense question. How could you possibly have fewer than zero items in a list?

Comment: @Dai I think he was using that as an example of the dotnet's implementation.

Comment: is this `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` or is it your own `List<T>`?

Comment: @bolov System.Collections.Generic.List<T>

Comment: The answer is no, you can move on to bigger and better things now

Comment: @Ken White Just to be on the safe side,because I noticed the Count is a int but not a uint

Comment: @Hanley It uses `int`/ `Int32` instead of `UInt32` / `uint` because the (now deprecated) Common Language Specification does not allow public use of unsigned types (because the BCL is intended to be consumed by languages other than C#, and those languages might not support unsigned types - surprisingly _many_ languages do not support unsigned types, (even [Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JZnj4eNHXE)) hence the restriction. But since .NET Core methinks the concept of CLS is dead - in any event **do not worry about it**.

Comment: There is no *safe side* in this case. You can't possibly have fewer than zero items in a list under any circumstances. Grab a pencil and paper. Write a list of the numbers 1 through 5. Start erasing them one by one. When you get back to a blank page, erase one more number off the list that you've erased entirely. Let me know how you did so if you figure it out.

Comment: Of course, `< 0` is _theoretically_ possible (since if you use the class in a non-threadsafe way then "all bets are off"). But if that is the case, you will have bigger issues - so don't worry about it. Just check `== 0`.

Comment: @KenWhite Simple: spam entries into and out-of a single `List<T>` concurrently using multiple-threads - though the fact it's unsigned is irrelevant because if it was unsigned it would just wrap-around to 4 billion or similar.

Comment: `SomeList.GetType().GetField("_size", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(SomeList, -1);`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation.

Comment: @Ken White I am just curious on it.

Comment: Related: [Why check whether List<T>.Count <= 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36595324/150605)*, [Difference between list.Count > 0 and list.Count != 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33050573/150605), [Why does .NET use int instead of uint in certain classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/782629/150605).  * I voted that question as a duplicate of this one because those answers focus more on _alternatives_ to testing `Count` (i.e. `Any()`) and gloss over _why_ `int Count` can(not) be negative, although now I'm having second thoughts about if these really are true duplicates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the comments:

> Just to be on the safe side, because I noticed the Count is a `int` but not a `uint`

#### TL;DR:

When the `List<T>` class was designed, Microsoft's .NET class library design rules meant that `UInt32` (aka `uint`) could not be used for any `public` members, so instead `Int32` (aka `int`) was used.

---

#### Longer answer:

- The reason why `Count` is an `int` (aka `Int32`) property instead of a `uint` (or `UInt32`) property is because the `List<T>` type was defined when the Common Language Specification (the "CLS") was still being respected by Microsoft.

  - Ostensibly, redistributable and reusable libraries should only use CLS-approved data-types and should avoid using non-CLS-compliant data-types.

    - `Int32` is CLS-compliant.
    - `UInt32` is **not** CLS-compliant.
  - The CLS exists because (at the time, around 2000-2005) Microsoft had this *grand design* for using .NET/CLR as the runtime *and* underlying type-system for *many radically different* programming languages - not just C# and VB.NET, but also Java ([yup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J_Sharp)), OCaml-style functional languages like F#, and [even JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET), [Python](https://ironpython.net/), and [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanger_(compiler)).
  - ...and many of those languages simply *don't support* unsigned integer types; in-fact, [high-profile languages like Java *still* don't support unsigned types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java).
  - ...so in order to *accommodate* languages used by masochists, like Java, the main .NET class library had to be designed with restrictions on the possible data-types they could use, which means they have to use signed integers to represent unsigned values.
  - **Therefore, if `Count` was typed as `UInt32` instead of `Int32` then users of those other languages couldn't use `List<T>.Count` at all**.
- Since .NET Core was released, I don't believe there has been any official deprecation of the Common Language Specification, but even if Microsoft hasn't officially abandoned it, the rest of the .NET ecosystem seems to have.

  - So I think [we can finally stop using CA1014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1014).

#### Can `List<T>.Count` ever be negative or otherwise invalid?

Provided you use a `List<T>` instance in a safe manner, then **no**, the `.Count` property will always return a value in the range `0` to `2^31` ([the *actual* maximum count of a `List<T>` is a different question which is already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2009246/159145)).

However, if you use a `List<T>` in a **thread-unsafe** manner (such as having 2 or more threads concurrently adding and removing items from a list without using `lock` correctly), or if you use tricks like reflection to override the `.Count` property's field value then **yes**, you can break things. So don't do that :)

#### Common Language Specification (CLS)

[The motivation for the CLS is described in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/common-type-system):

> - To enable full interoperability scenarios, all objects that are created in code must rely on some commonality in the languages that are consuming them (are their callers).
> - Since there are numerous different languages, .NET has specified those commonalities in something called the Common Language Specification (CLS).

[The Common Language Specification is described in this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence), which has a list of types built-in to .NET but which are *verboten* for use in CLS-compliant frameworks and redistributable libraries.

- `System.SByte` aka `sbyte`.

  - Signed octet value.
  - This is the only *signed*, as opposed to unsigned, type prohibited by the CLS.
  - Curiously, Java actually has a *signed* byte type.
- `System.UInt16` aka `ushort`.
- `System.UInt32` aka `uint`.
- `System.UInt64` aka `ulong`.
- `System.UIntPtr`.

Also:

> - The rules for CLS compliance apply only to a component's public interface, not to its private implementation.
> - For example, unsigned integers other than `Byte` are not CLS-compliant [...].

Answer (score 3):

No, the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,137) (which only apply for .NET Framework) for that property is

```
public int Count {
   get {
       Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
       return _size; 
   }
}
```

which due to how [Contract.Ensures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052640/how-does-contract-ensures-work) works, guarantee it will never return less than zero.

As for [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs), that property is simply

```
public int Count => _size;
```

`_size` itself can't ever get below zero according to all the assignments in the code.

Comment: Catch: Code Contracts are not supported in .NET Core nor .NET 5+.

Comment: "`_size` itself can't ever get below zero according to all the assignments in the code." - **it can** if you use a `List<T>` in thread-unsafe way.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can, why even ask. Here is some blasphemy:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TotalGarbageTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Blasphemy()
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        list.GetType().GetField("_size", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(list, -666);
        Assert.AreEqual(-666, list.Count);
    }
}
```

**PS** Now you are probably corrupted by knowledge, but meh, whatever.

Comment: I wonder if maybe we _should_ teach reflection early-on, just so people learn to to never use it…

Comment: There is darker black magic than just reflection if you remember you have access to modifying IL and can blow up kernel with admin rights ****sinister laugh****

Comment: You can’t “blow up the [OS] kernel” by manipulating IL because you can’t run the CLR inside an OS kernel.

Comment: While I appreciate good trolling this is really bad guidance... unfortunately there is very high chance OP now will claim that all checks for `.Count` (and `.Count()`... and `.Length`) should check for negative values too and annoy everyone around them.